# I have an Izuzu NPR and have a warning light the is showing exhaust stack error. Any idea of what that might be

Tags: cel, isuzu

I have a 2002 Izuzu NPR with a light on the dashboard.
I looked it up and it is saying it is a stack error.
Any idea of what I am looking for?
I bought the truck used and no manuals came with it.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!